# Search in an Object Array with more than one condition jQuery grep()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, search

I have an Object Array with Key-Value pair on jQuery like this

[image]

And I am searching in these arrays to find a match with with an `id` that I will provide so I have

```
var result = $.grep(records, function(e){ return e.id== id; });
```

So this looks like, search a record in the array with an `id` of whatever the value of `id` that i passed it. It works fine but what if I want to pass two parameters to match the records in the array? let's say `columnheader` and `parent_colheader`? What will my previous

```
var result = $.grep(records, function(e){ return e.id== id; });
```

syntax should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple variables with **&&**

```
var id = 1;
var columnheader = 'test';
var parent_colheader = 'test';
var result = $.grep(records, function(e) {
    return e.id == id && e.columnheader == columnheader && e.parent_colheader == parent_colheader;
});
```

Comment: oh it's just the &&? I never knew that it's possible :D Thanks, let me try :)